# Compare line by line two files with multiple columns using bash using comperatives

Tags: if-statement, awk, compare, multiple-columns

I have two files:

file1:

```
a b 30 d
a b 50 d
```

and file2:

```
a b 20 d
a b 60 d
```

the preferred output file file_output:

```
a b 20 d
a b 50 d
```

I want to compare each file line by line and I want to print in the output file,  the line in which the number in the 3rd column is smaller using awk.

I tried something like:

```
awk '  NR==FNR { arr[$3];next} arr[$3] < $3 ' file1 file2 > file_output
```

but it prints only the smaller for file1 and not for file2

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'FNR==NR {f3[FNR]=$3;a[FNR]=$0;next} FNR in a {print ($3<f3[FNR])?$0:a[FNR]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: If you have time someday. I would appreciate if you explain it step by step your answer.

Comment: ok, thanks for "sharing". What is a "decimal" number in your view? Could you provide a a "non-working" sample?